# Reshape a series of repeated data in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame in wide format with repeated measurments

```
id method    day1 day2 day3
1   A         4,5   6    5,6
2.  B          3   2,5    5
3   C          2    4,2   3
```

I want to reshape it to a format like

```
Method    Time  value
A        Day1    4,5
A        Day2     6
A        Day3     5,6
B        Day1     3
B        Day2     2,5
B        Day3     5
C...................
```

But the reshape function for changing wide to long only gives me each group seperately, do any one have an idea about reshaping in order?

Comment: Please edit your post to fix the data format and the discrepancies, for example between `day` and `Day`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `melt` from `reshape2` to convert from 'wide' to 'long' format.  We specify the column index in the `measure`.

```
library(reshape2)
dM <- melt(df1, measure=3:5)[-1]
```

and then `order` the 'method' column to get the expected output

```
dM1 <- dM[order(dM$method),]
row.names(dM1) <- NULL
dM1
#    method variable value
#1      A     Day1   4,5
#2      A     day2     6
#3      A     day3   5,6
#4      B     Day1     3
#5      B     day2   2,5
#6      B     day3     5
#7      C     Day1     2
#8      C     day2   4,2
#9      C     day3     3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3), method = c("A", "B", "C"),
Day1 = c("4,5", 
"3", "2"), day2 = c("6", "2,5", "4,2"), day3 = c("5,6", "5", 
"3")), .Names = c("id", "method", "Day1", "day2", "day3"),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thank you but i need to take Anova test for each group so i want each method in one group like the second data frame i wrote

Comment: @Madamespring I don't find any difference between the expected output you showed and the one I got.  Regarding the `Anova` test, it is a different question

Comment: I used order but i t reshapes the dataframe to wide format again, and since my data set is big i can not do the structure function you recomended for each elements :(

Comment: @Madamespring  You have to do `order` after the `melt`.  I am not sure what is happening at your end.